# Fundamental constants

Tags: physical-constants

Alpha is one of the fundamental constants in physics. If it had not the precise value that it has, there would be no life in the universe.

One of these fundamental constants is the fine-structure constant, or alpha, which is the coupling constant for the electromagnetic force and equal to about 1/137.0359. My question is what are the odds it would have that value? How unlikely Is it to have that value?

Comment: Hi S. Gloobal, welcome to Physics stack exchange. Sorry about the downvotes. Please don't be discouraged by this and continue being curious. First it's because you asserted it as fact that life wouldn't exist if alpha was slightly different - a statement from popular science communication that isn't backed up by facts. Second it's because of the strange writing. You started with "alpha is one of the fundamental constants" then two sentences later "one of those fundamental constants is alpha".

Comment: To answer "what are the odds" of something, it needs to be one of a number of possible outcomes, each equally likely or else with well defined probabilities.  For $\alpha$ we have no information on other possibilities.  It's kind of like asking "What are the odds that Napoleon Bonaparte became Emperor of France?" It's just a known fact, that doesn't have a meaningful probability

Answer (score 2):

Probabilities are inferences of hypothetical future measurements of countable frequency (how many times you will win the game divided by how many times you will play the game). They are inferred on the basis of past measurements of a (possibly only very distantly related) countable frequency. Such measurements are logically extended into a stochastic mathematical model, which can be tested by making additional measurements and seeing if they comport with the model's predictions. Next one takes measurements of the system whose future state is being predicted, inputs those measurements into the model, and outputs a probabilistic prediction.

If there is no sample set in which to count a frequency (e.g. measurements of universes other than our own), there is no probability.

There is no probability for a past event, except insofar as one really means the probability of repeating that past event in some hypothetical future in which you started over with the conditions measured at some time prior to the past event.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this question is unanswerable. We don't know what gave rise to the universe. We don't know what range of possible values the fundamental constants have. In fact, we don't even know that the fundamental constants are chosen randomly.

This statement you reference (that $\alpha$ might be different in different universes or that it might be randomly chosen from a range of values) comes partially from string theory, which predicts a wide range of different universes. I'm not a string theory expert so people in the comments can discuss this. But I believe even in string theory the question can't be answered - it describes a massive variety of different universes, but the observed physics in those universes can't actually be predicted. And note that in many of those universes we have a completely different set of particles with completely different interactions, not just the same particles with different constants. And finally string theory doesn't even concretely say that the universe is randomly chosen from a particular group of possibilities.

But the idea that there might be different universes with different fundamental constants is definitely older than string theory. It's just a guess about how the universe *might* work. It's a guess that there might be many universes with different fundamental constants, and that beings are only conscious to observe the universe with a certain combination of fundamental constants. The idea didn't come from a particular theory that made a specific probability prediction.

Comment: If alpha were just 4% bigger or smaller than it is, stars wouldn't be able to make carbon and oxygen, which would have made it impossible for life as we know it to exist. Now we are assuming this is the only universe since there's no possible way of knowing about another universe

Comment: @S.Gloobal I'm aware of such arguments, but I think it's incredibly shortsighted to assume that in a universe with 4% bigger alpha the only thing that would be different was that stars would stop fusing earlier. I think it's also incredibly shortsighted to assume that all possible forms of life require carbon and oxygen, and that _radically different universes_ (different particles with different interactions) wouldn't also support radically different forms of life. So I think these kinds of calculations, while interesting, don't actually help at all to calculate "the probability of life."

Comment: I understand that but for the sake of the question we are simply going by what we know instead of making unnecessary assumptions such there could be different biological life forms other than the ones we are acquainted with. We don't have any evidence that there are different life forms or could be different life forms. So let's only assume what we know for the sake of the question

Comment: @S.Gloobal Let's change the discussion a bit. It seems like you haven't read my answer. Your comments (which you have put on my answer) seem to address the comment that I put under your question. In this answer, I don't discuss what particular values of $\alpha$ give rise to life. I explain why our current understanding of the universe makes this question impossible to answer even if you take it as fact that 4% is the acceptable range for $\alpha$

Comment: OK forget about life for a moment. What is the probably that electromagnetic force what equal that value rather than simply a different value?

Comment: @S.Gloobal read the answer, not just comments. It explains why the question you're asking is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer this with an analogy from Sabine Hossenfelder's new book.

Imagine you took out a sheet of paper from a pouch with many sheets of paper.
The sheet of paper said 1,326,784. But, you can't open the pouch or see anything in it again.

You cannot know the probability that this particular number came up with this set up.

The pouch could be filled with only sheets of paper that have 1,326,784, in which case the probability is 100%. It could also have every integer, or every even number up to 2 million.

Either way, because we can't predict the values of constants in other universes (I'm sure there are theories that do this, but my knowledge is lacking on this, so hopefully someone in the comments will answer that), or observe them in other universes, we don't know.

It is possible that because of some factors, if other universes exist, or this universe is re-created, or something, that the same alpha constant comes up every time.

It is also possible that every universe gives a different value, and that they will be drastically different.

Talking about probability in such a situation where we don't know the range of the values, or anything other than one event, is impossible.

Please feel free to ask more questions, or point out any inaccuracies (I'm sure there are quite a few!) in the comments.